# CSS for printing: 210mm*297mm on A4 = overflow?

Tags: html, css, printing

Here is a simple HTML code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      .page {
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        background: #DD5555;
      }

      @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
      }

      @media print {
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
        .page {
          width: 210mm;
          height: 297mm;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">This is a test page</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can copy/paste it to check.

My problem is :
When I try the print-preview in Google Chrome the "page" element overflow the first page.

This is strange because A4 dimensions are 210*297mm

Does someone know why ?

(BTW: I'm looking for some good and complete tutorial about CSS printing techniques)

---

> Note : Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m

Comment: My first guess would be print margins (almost no printer can print up to the edge of the paper). Can you try with 200x287mm? 5mm margin should be enough for most printers today.

Comment: strange : it's worse, the overflow is bigger

Comment: That's odd; check the print options. Is there something like "scale to fit the paper size"? Other things that could have an influence: header and footer, margins of elements around `.page` (check the coordinates in the dev tools)

Comment: Print to PDF : Margin=None ; Background Graphics : Yes

Comment: My chrome is in French so I'm guessing options' name

Comment: There is no other elements around `.page` except `body`. But `body` has `margin:0` when printing

Comment: `body` is a child of the `html` element. That's why you should check the exact pixel positions/sizes in the dev tools.

Comment: Try with a size of 150x200mm and then make it bigger until it overflows. Also, a grey or yellow background will help to see what is `.page` and what are elements outside.

Comment: the page element is already red and fill the entire page (and the top of the second page = the overflow part)

Comment: The code above works with a height of 290mm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Chrome 41.0.2272.118. Can you try again with all plugins disabled?

Comment: All plugins disabled : still not working. The overflow is ~1-2px tall

Comment: `height: 296.994mm;` WORKS // `height: 296.995mm;` OVERFLOW

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug, but I can be solved by replacing `height: 297mm;` with `height: 296.994mm;`. (The difference in other browser should not be visible)

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing setting the paper size in mm. Issue has gone for me:

```
@media print {  
  @page {
    size: 210mm 297mm;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```